# How to select whether or not a specific date is before X amount of years? - Presto SQL

Tags: sql, date, intervals, presto

I'm trying to select whether or not the date value in one of my columns takes place before a certain amount of years.

The code I'm trying out:

```
SELECT CASE
WHEN CAST(my_date AS DATE) + INTERVAL '10' YEAR < CURRENT_DATE THEN 'OVER 10 YEARS AGO'
ELSE NULL AS date_check
```

My expected output should be `NULL` for the dates I'm using (e.g. `2019-09-30`) as they fall within the last 10 years, but for some reason, I'm getting `OVER 10 YEARS AGO` for everything.

When I test with values actually over 10 years ago (e.g. `2010-07-17`), I'm also getting `OVER 10 YEARS AGO` as expected, however.

How is it possible to achieve what I'm trying to do? What appears to be wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte (my_date) AS (
          SELECT current_date - INTERVAL '11' YEAR UNION
          SELECT '2010-07-17' UNION
          SELECT '2019-09-30'
     )
SELECT CASE
          WHEN CAST(my_date AS DATE) + INTERVAL '10' YEAR < CURRENT_DATE
          THEN 'OVER 10 YEARS AGO'
          ELSE NULL
        END AS date_check
 FROM cte
;
```

Having said that, it's best to perform your calculation against the literal, not your column:

```
WITH cte (my_date) AS (
          SELECT current_date - INTERVAL '11' YEAR UNION
          SELECT '2010-07-17' UNION
          SELECT '2019-09-30'
     )
SELECT CASE
          WHEN CAST(my_date AS DATE) < CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '10' YEAR
          THEN 'OVER 10 YEARS AGO'
          ELSE NULL
        END AS date_check
 FROM cte
;
```

and, if possible, use the correct type without CAST.

[Full test case](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=de26f933207b7fada28f24c9af03b2c6)

Comment: Thanks for this! Turns out my original code actually works too if I used the literal instead of my column value